# On the LM386 opamp Module, why I am getting an output without giving input

Tags: operational-amplifier, lm386, module

I am using an [LM386 opamp Module from Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08DCQ4P48/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I am powering it with a 5V input (just to power it, not intending to amplify anything at this point). Nevertheless a multimeter measures an amplified output of around 1v-2v.

When I put an actual input that I want to amplify nothing really changes. Why I am getting an output without giving input?

[image: Multimeter showing unintended amplified output voltage]

Comment: Could you post the schematics of the board?

Comment: The LM386 is not an OPAMP. It's a small Audio Power amp.

Comment: [LM386](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) Audio Amplifier datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

The module is an AC amplifier, but you're measuring a DC voltage. What you're actually seeing is the leakage current through the module's output capacitor creating a voltage drop across the 10 MΩ input resistance of your meter.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually able to measure the voltage change but only after connecting a speaker to it

Comment: The speaker "shorted out" the leakage current. You'll get better results if you use the AC volts function of the meter.